# PostgreSQL (WITH RECURSIVE)

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that returns all dates between 01/01/2011 and 12/31/2041 (excluding Saturdays and sundays). It's working fine, but when I try to put the filter "TRIM(TO_CHAR(dt, 'DAY')) NOT IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')" in the WITH, It only returns one row. Any suggestions? Please keep in mind that i'm brand new to PostgreSQL.

```
   WITH RECURSIVE bd(dt,rn) AS 
    (
     SELECT
           TO_DATE('01/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS dt,
           1 AS rn
     UNION
     SELECT
          dt + 1, rn + 1
     FROM
          bd
     WHERE
          dt BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('12/31/2041', 'MM/DD/YYYY') - 1  
    )
    SELECT
         dt, rn
    FROM
         bd
    WHERE TRIM(TO_CHAR(dt, 'DAY')) NOT IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')
```

Comment: Your query works fine for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=47c8fe08007ae43abfffd56421fdaee5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a recursive query. This can be done much easier using `generate_series()`

```
select t.dt::date
from generate_series(date '2011-01-01', date '2014-12-31', interval '1 day') as t(dt)
where extract(isodow from t.dt) not in (6,7);
```

Comment: But can you tell me what  t(dt) does? I'm assuming it's an alias.

Comment: @edavis Yes, it's an alias to the generate_series.

Comment: @edavis: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES

Comment: Thanks. I was curious about the parentheses around the dt "t(dt)' I've never seen an alias like that.